# How can install4j condition check if launcher is UI or console application launcher?

Tags: launcher, install4j

I'd like to display different license text if I'm running on the console or with a UI (plain text vs html text).   I think I can do this via conditions on my screens but I'm unsure of how to determine what kind of launcher is running.

I think I'd use   LauncherSetup.getType() and can get LauncherSetup getLauncherById(java.lang.String id) if I can figure out the id of the running launch, but I'm not sure how to get the running Launcher's id.

Please let me know if you have a solution for this situation.  If now, I'll post my code when I've figured out how to get the launcherID

Thanks

Peter

Comment: If you are really talking about the generated launchers, then you have separate console and GUI launchers and you can use a different main class or VM parameters to tell your code if it's a console or a GUI launcher. Or are you talking about the GUI and console mode of the installer?

Comment: Ingo,  I'm talking about the GUI and the console mode of the installer.  I don't have different launchers.  My real problem is that html tags show up in the license file during console mode which looks bad.  I figured I could process the file at build time into two files and then only display the right one based on mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the "Display license agreement" screen twice. On the first instance, use the HTML file and set the condition expression to `!context.isConsole()`, on the second instance, use the plain text file and set the condition expression to `!context.isConsole()`.

However, install4j can automatically convert the HTML text to plain text in console mode. This only works if your HTML file starts with `<html>`.